# Can't Write Custom Widget Code In One ECHO

Tags: functions, widgets, widget-text

I am creating a WordPress custom widget and I created the below one that is working fine when I add it in `function.php`.

```
<?php
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Most Commented Post Widget
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
class show_popular_commented extends WP_Widget {

function show_popular_commented() {
 $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'show_popular_commented', 'description' => __('Show your popular commented posts.'));
 $this->WP_Widget('show_popular_commented', __('EXE_Widgets - Popular Commented Posts'), $widget_ops);
 }

function widget($args, $instance){
 extract($args);
 $title = $instance['title'];
 $postscount = $instance['posts'];
//Show The Most Commented Posts
 global $postcount;
 $myposts = get_posts(array('orderby' => 'comment_count','numberposts' =>$postscount));
 echo $before_widget . $before_title . $title . $after_title; //Widget Data
 echo '
 <style type="text/css">
 .commented_post {display:block;margin:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;}
 .commented_post h4{font-size:16px;clear:both;display:block;}
 .commented_post p{font-size:13px;text-align:justify;line-height:18px;margin:10px 0;}
 </style>
 ';
 foreach($myposts as $post){
 setup_postdata($post);
 echo '<div class="commented_post">';
 echo '<h4><a href="';
 echo the_permalink();
 echo '">';
 echo the_title();
 echo'</a></h4>';
 echo the_excerpt();
 echo '</div>';
 }
 echo $after_widget;  //Widget Data
//Show The Most Commented Posts
 }


function update($newInstance, $oldInstance){
 $instance = $oldInstance;
 $instance['title'] = strip_tags($newInstance['title']);
 $instance['posts'] = $newInstance['posts'];
 return $instance;
 }

function form($instance){
 if(empty($instance['title'])){ $instance['title'] = '';}{
 echo '<p><label  for="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'">' . __('Title:') . ' </label><input style="width:100%;" id="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'"  name="'.$this->get_field_name('title').'" type="text"  value="'.$instance['title'].'" /></p>';
 }
 if(empty($instance['posts'])){ $instance['posts'] = '';}{
 echo '<p><label  for="'.$this->get_field_id('posts').'">' . __('Number of Posts:',  'widgets') . ' </label><input style="width:50px;" id="'.$this->get_field_id('posts').'"  name="'.$this->get_field_name('posts').'" type="text"  value="'.$instance['posts'].'" /></p>';
 }
 echo '<input type="hidden" id="custom_recent" name="custom_recent" value="1" />';
 }

 }

add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("show_popular_commented");'));
?>
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to use too many `echo'';` as I used in the above code...

```
 echo '<div class="commented_post">';
 echo '<h4><a href="';
 echo the_permalink();
 echo '">';
 echo the_title();
 echo'</a></h4>';
 echo the_excerpt();
 echo '</div>';
```

But when I use one `echo'';` and code the above one like below then my widget is not working properly. It is getting all variables data but not the HTML tags that I wrote in `echo'';`...

```
 echo '<div class="commented_post"><h4><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></h4>'.the_excerpt().'</div>';
```

Can you answer me why it is not accepting single `echo'';`?

Comment: Look at the Widget API. You should never use `extract()` and most of all never use `create_function()`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Can you suggest me good alternative or can edit the code? In other way, below answer is now working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your first example is also incorrect, but the problem is not apparent. You're using template tags that themselves `echo` their content. For example, you can write simply:

```
the_permalink();
```

without `echo`, and the permalink will be output. This is because that function `echo`es its value. To output the permalink within an echo or variable assignment you need to use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

```
echo get_permalink()
```

Just about all WordPress template tags have equivalent `get_` versions, or an argument that toggles `echo` and `return`, like [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title):

```
the_title( '', '', false );
```

Here the 3rd parameter toggles `echo` (true) or `return` (false).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your answer, Now I am using the mentioned `echo'';` and its working fine. Mine new is  `echo '<div class="commented_post"><h4><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.the_title( '', '', false ).'</a></h4><p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p></div>';`...

Answer (score 1):

This should just be an extension to the answer by @Milo

There are a couple of flaws in your code

- You should not be using `extract()`. It is hard to debug and causes unexpected output. All instances of `extract()` was removed from core
- PHP 5.2 is dead, and for that matter 5.3 aswell. `create_function()` is pre 5.3. This is one big security risk as it uses `eval()` which should be avoided at all cost. The correct way is just to use `function()`
- Rather use `WP_Query` in place of `get_posts()`. `WP_Query` results get cached making it faster
- Class name words should start with camelcase
- Make proper use of opening and closing php tag to avoid the overwhelming use of `echo`

I have rewritten your complete widget to align it with the current [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API). You can just make the tweaks you want to add or remove

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Most Commented Post Widget
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
class Show_Popular_Commented extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'show_popular_commented', 
            __( 'Popular Commented Posts' ), 
            array( 'description' => __( 'Show your popular commented posts.' ), 
            ) 
        );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'show_popular_commented';

        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $cache = array();
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'widget_commented_posts', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = array();
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        $title          = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Commented Posts' );
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );
        $number         = ( ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number ) {
            $number = 5;
        }

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for the Commented Posts widget.
         *
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         * @see WP_Query::get_posts()
         *
         * @param array $args An array of arguments used to retrieve the commented posts.
         */
        $query_args = [
            'posts_per_page'    => $number,
            'orderby'           => 'comment_count',
        ];
        $q = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'comment_posts_args', $query_args ) );

        if( $q->have_posts() ) {

            echo $args['before_widget'];
            if ( $title ) {
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
            }               

            while( $q->have_posts() ) {
                $q->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="commented_post">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .commented_post {display:block;margin:10px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;}
                        .commented_post h4{font-size:16px;clear:both;display:block;}
                        .commented_post p{font-size:13px;text-align:justify;line-height:18px;margin:10px 0;}
                    </style>

                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' ); ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-summary">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

                </div><!-- #post-## -->

                <?php
            }


            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
            echo $args['after_widget']; 

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_commented_posts', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance                   = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['number']         = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset( $alloptions['widget_comment_post'] ) )
            delete_option( 'widget_comment_post' );

        return $instance;
    }

    public function flush_widget_cache() {
        wp_cache_delete( 'widget_commented_posts', 'widget' );
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {

        $title      = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $number     = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>

    <?php
    }

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function () {
    register_widget( 'Show_Popular_Commented' );
});
```

Comment: My pleasure. I hope it helps. Enjoy :-)